# Don't create object when if condition is not met in __init__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a class that maps a database object

```
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        ...SQL request with id as key...
        if len(rows) == 1:
            ...maps columns as my_obj attributes...
            self.exists = True
        else:
            self.exists = False
```

With such design, an object is created each time, and we check if it is present in database with .exists attribute.

```
my_obj = MyObj(id=15)
if my_obj.exists:
    ...do stuff...
```

It works.

But I suspect there is a cleaner way to init, and we would just have to check like that:

```
 my_obj = MyObj(id=15)
 if my_obj:
     ...do stuff...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this in `__init__`, because that method is run *after* the new instance is created.

You *can* do it with [`object.__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) however, this is run to create the instance in the first place. Because it is normally supposed to return that new instance, you could also choose to return *something else* (like `None`).

You could use it like this:

```
class MyObj:
    def __new__(cls, id):
        # ...SQL request with id as key...
        if not rows:
            # no rows, so no data. Return `None`.
            return None

        # create a new instance and set attributes on it
        instance = super().__new__(cls)  # empty instance
        instance.rows = ...
        return instance
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to use \_\_del\_\_() method in the \_\_init\_\_() ? Usually I handle it with global class array (called _instances_) where I push _self_ if my condition is true. After I just have to loop thru _MyClass.instances_.

Comment: nope, I tried but doesn't work AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute '__del__'

Comment: @martijn, why did you put the instance = super()... seems to work well with 'self' instead of 'cls' and self.rows / return self

Comment: @comte: You can't use `__del__` because that is only called when the number of references to the instance drops to 0. You are assigning the object to `my_obj` so it is still references and won't be deleted. You can't delete the object by calling `__del__`; that hook is called *after* it is decided to delete the object; you use it to clean up before it is deleted entirely.

Comment: @comte: `__new__` is called *with the class as first argument*, not with an instance. The method is supposed to *create* an instance, so it doesn't exist yet when the method is called. You can use any name you like for that first argument, but `cls` is the convention as it makes it clear we have a class reference here, not an instance. I used `super()` to ask the normal machinery (`object.__new__`) to create the instance for me first, so we can use it to set attributes on, etc. I've moved it down a little in my latest edit, so this is clearer.

Comment: just to finish on this topic, I feel that instance.rows = ... should be in __init__(self, id), because it is instance initialization... but it would incur 2 identicals SQL calls (1 in new to know if record exists and another in init to assign to instance attributes)... kind of overkill.

Comment: Solution is nice, but I would not add an SQL query into `__new__` or even in `__init__`. IMHO it is more clear if the object is created with a very simple `__init__`, then with an object method do the SQL and if it retuns 0 rows (e.g. myobj.rownum == 0), then drop it.